# Convert unicode string into NFC in Rust

Tags: unicode, rust

Let's say I have a `std::String`, contents unknown, that like "Mañana" has combining characters and I want to convert it to unicode NFC, a la [String.prototype.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) in Javascript or [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) in Python.

I found [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-normalization) on crates.io but it seems to contain only methods for working with individual characters. How would I convert an entire string? Convert to bytes and iterate pairwise and check for combining characters using the functions in that crate? What would that even look like in rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use the `unicode_normalization` crate. More specifically, check out the [`nfc`](https://docs.rs/unicode-normalization/0.1.12/unicode_normalization/trait.UnicodeNormalization.html#tymethod.nfc) method.

Comment: Ok, pretty new to Rust, how do I use that method? Can you give me an example? I didn't even see it when I looked over the docs.

Comment: `"your string".nfc().collect::<String>()`

Comment: @MartinGallagher so importing that crate with `use unicode_normalization::UnicodeNormalization;` has the side effect of modifying strings to support the trait?

Comment: @MartinGallagher it did. Thanks!